# Transition from Erb to Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to rewrite views of existing Rails project to Slim. I've added `gem 'slim-rails'` to my `Gemfile` and installed it via Bundler. Now when I'm visiting **localhost:3000**, it returns me

```
Missing template home/front, application/front with {
    :locale=>[:en],
    :formats=>[:html],
    :variants=>[],
    :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]
}.
```

Obviusly something went wrong with handlers, but I even don't know where to start at.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rename files to `.html.slim` ?

Comment: @miler350 I've done it already of course

Comment: Restart server? Sorry, to ask these basic questions but that error shows it can't find template which generally means it either can't find the slim file or it can't find the slim gem. Slim should appear in your handlers. :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim]

Comment: I've even done `rm -rf vendor/bundle && bundler install --path=vendor/bundle` few times

Comment: https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails/issues/55  Check the placement of your gem. According to this error, it has given issues before.